# Combining GUM Type A and Type B uncertainties

Tags: mean, repeated-measures, standard-deviation, measurement-error, uncertainty

Assume $N$ measurements of the same parameter, i.e. a surface temperature $\vartheta_\mathrm{surf}$, were obtained using one single measuring chain (temperature sensor, cables, ADC ...).

Furthermore, the uncertainty of each single temperature reading $\vartheta_\mathrm{surf,i}$ ($i = 1 \dots N)$ was estimated as $u(\vartheta_\mathrm{surf,i})$ using manufacturers' specifications which can be interpreted as a [GUM](https://www.bipm.org/documents/20126/2071204/JCGM_100_2008_E.pdf/cb0ef43f-baa5-11cf-3f85-4dcd86f77bd6) Type B uncertainty.

However, the obtained $\vartheta_\mathrm{surf,i}$ should be used to get an estimate of the surface temperature $\vartheta_\mathrm{surf}$. For this, the mean of all $\vartheta_\mathrm{surf,i}$ $(i = 1 \dots N)$ is calculated. Calculating the [standard deviation of the mean (aka standard error)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error) can be interpreted as a GUM Type A uncertainty.

Is there any way to consider the Type B uncertainties when calculating the mean or to "combine" both types of uncertainties? Unfortunately, I did not find any hint about this in the [GUM](https://www.bipm.org/documents/20126/2071204/JCGM_100_2008_E.pdf/cb0ef43f-baa5-11cf-3f85-4dcd86f77bd6) (or misread it).